# Script to launch mutiple terminal of terminator

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, terminator

I am new to terminator, where I need to launch 4 terminal. I have a script  `run1.sh` which I want to run on first two terminal simultaneously and script `run2.sh` in other two terminal simultaneously.

[image]

But I want to launch the above four terminal by some script let say by script `start.sh` so that it itself start the terminator and split the terminator in four window and run the script `run1.sh` in first two window and `run2.sh` in other two window. Please suggest me relevant approach (it could be any python/bash/perl), as I could able to start the four window of terminator by manually and executing the command separately, which I want to do by some script. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following shellscript works for me in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. If you have another desktop environment, you should edit the script's `wcorr` and `hcorr` values in order to match the screen.

I suggest the name `l4t` for the shellscript,

```
#!/bin/bash

wcorr=68  # manual fix for vertical panels
hcorr=26  # manual fix for horizontal panels


tmps=$(LANG=C xrandr|grep -om1 'current.*,')
tmps=${tmps/,}
tmps=${tmps/current }
echo "screen resolution = $tmps pixels"
wscr=${tmps/ x*}
hscr=${tmps/*x }
wter=$(( (wscr-wcorr)/2 ))
hter=$(( (hscr-hcorr)/2 ))
echo "terminal width  = $wter pixels"
echo "terminal height = $hter pixels"

terminator --borderless --geometry="${wter}x${hter}+0+0" -x run1.sh &
terminator --borderless --geometry="${wter}x${hter}+0-0" -x run1.sh &
terminator --borderless --geometry="${wter}x${hter}-0+0" -x run2.sh &
terminator --borderless --geometry="${wter}x${hter}-0-0" -x run2.sh &
```

I have tested the function with the following scripts `run1.sh` and `run1.sh`

`run1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=0
while [ $cnt -lt 10 ]
do
 echo -n "$cnt"
 sleep 1
 cnt=$((cnt+1))
done
echo ""
bash
```

`run1.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=9
while [ $cnt -ge 0 ]
do
 echo -n "$cnt"
 sleep 1
 cnt=$((cnt-1))
done
echo ""
bash
```

I put a bash command at the end of these scripts. Otherwise the terminal windows would be closed after the scripts have finished. You may want to do something else.

Make the three shellscripts executable

```
chmod +x l4t run1.sh run2.sh
```

and move them to a directory in PATH,

```
mv l4t run1.sh run2.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

Now you can run them just with the name like any other command.

```
l4t
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But you did not mentioned how to start run1.sh and run2.sh from the above script ?

Comment: @Arya, I have modified my answer to include running those scripts. Does it work as you want it to work?

Comment: @Arya, I added the option `--borderless` and modified `hcorr`, which means that the [outer] title bar of the window is removed and there is more space for lines in each terminator window.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could give a try to **tmux** with **tmuxinator**

```
sudo apt install tmux tmuxinator
```

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/

https://tmuxcheatsheet.com/

https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can refer to this link for a straightforward approach, I have posted it on my github:
https://github.com/kgnandanwar/Script-to-launch-mutiple-terminal-of-terminator

Step 1: Create the necessary directory and an empty configuration file

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/terminator/
touch ~/.config/terminator/config
nano ~/.config/terminator/config
```

Step 2: Copy-Paste the following code(Make sure to adjust the display resolution in line 19 of the following code as per your PC

```
[global_config]
  title_hide_sizetext = True
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
  suppress_multiple_term_dialog = True
[keybindings]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    cursor_blink = False
    font = DejaVu Sans Mono 9
    scrollback_infinite = True
[layouts]
  [[default]]

    [[[root]]]
      position = -4:0
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1870, 1020

    [[[grand]]]
      position = 536
      type = HPaned
      order = 0
      parent = root
    [[[left]]]
      position = 942
      type = VPaned
      order = 0
      parent = grand
    [[[right]]]
      position = 942
      type = VPaned
      order = 1
      parent = grand

    [[[terminal1]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = left
    [[[terminal2]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = left

    [[[terminal3]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = right
      command = ""
    [[[terminal4]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = right
[plugins]
```